Making a mixture of Gaussians unidentifiable?
Suppose that $A$ is a random variable such that $P(A=\sigma_{1})=P(A=\sigma_{2})=0.5$ for some $0<\sigma_{1}<\sigma_{2}$, and
$$X\mid A\sim\mathcal{N}(0,A).$$
In words, the distribution of $X$ is a mixture of two Gaussians with the same means and different standard deviations.
I am seeking some random variable $\hat{X}$ such that $A\rightarrow X\rightarrow \hat{X}$, $I(X;\hat{X})>0$ ($\hat{X}$ and $X$ are statistically dependent), and $I(A;\hat{X})=0$ ($A$ and $\hat{X}$ are statistically independent). Optimally, I would want $I(X;\hat{X})$ to be as large as possible.
I was trying to somehow manipulate each realization $x\sim p_{X}$ by using the conditional probability $P(A=\sigma_{1}|X=x)$, but I can't find something that works. I also couldn't find any related problem in the literature, but perhaps I am missing something.
Any suggestions?

Perhaps try something like $\frac{X}{A}$.

Or perhaps $\text{sign}(X)$

@Henry Sorry, in the original post I forgot to add the condition: $A\rightarrow X\rightarrow \hat{X}$. My bad. Just updated it.
$\text{sign}(X)$ indeed works! But I would like to find something less trivial, with larger $I(X;\hat{X})$. To preserve more information about $X$.

What do $\rightarrow$ and $I$ represent?

@ZackFisher $I(X;\hat{X})$ is the mutual information between $X$ and $\hat{X}$. $A\rightarrow X\rightarrow \hat{X}$ represents a Markov chain, such that $A$ and $\hat{X}$ are statistically independent given $X$.

@GuyOhayon Do you mean $I(A;\hat{X} \mid X)=0$, instead of $I(A;\hat{X})=0$?

@ZackFisher nope, I mean $I(A;\hat{X})=0$. $I(A;\hat{X}|X)=0$ is something I am assuming to hold.

The magnitude of $X$ provides information about the magnitude of $A$ (so for example large $X$ is more likely to be associated with large $A=\sigma_2$ than with small $A=\sigma_1$) so

either you take out that association as with $\frac XA\sim\mathcal{N}(0,1)$, though apparently you would prefer a function just of $X$ rather than $X$ and $A$,
or you lose the magnitude information as with $\text{sign}(X)$.


Thank you! This is very helpful and your solution works. Do you think that we cannot do anything better (in terms of $I(X;\hat{X})$)?
